# can not read property 'score' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can not read property 'score' of undefined this is a tic tac toe game using minimax algorithm. Here is the pen for my whole application.

https://codepen.io/MartinaMF/pen/LjNdNN

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var turns=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    var computerTurn;
    var playerTurn;
    var iter=0;
    var count=0;

  function winCondition(turnArray,currentTurn){
    if((turnArray[0]===currentTurn && turnArray[1]===currentTurn && turnArray[2]===currentTurn)||
       (turnArray[3]===currentTurn && turnArray[4]===currentTurn && turnArray[5]===currentTurn)||
       (turnArray[6]===currentTurn && turnArray[7]===currentTurn && turnArray[8]===currentTurn)||
       (turnArray[0]===currentTurn && turnArray[3]===currentTurn && turnArray[6]===currentTurn)||
       (turnArray[1]===currentTurn && turnArray[4]===currentTurn && turnArray[7]===currentTurn)||
       (turnArray[2]===currentTurn && turnArray[5]===currentTurn && turnArray[8]===currentTurn)||
       (turnArray[0]===currentTurn && turnArray[4]===currentTurn && turnArray[8]===currentTurn)||
        (turnArray[2]===currentTurn && turnArray[4]===currentTurn && turnArray[6]===currentTurn)){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;} 

  }
  function availableSpots(Arr){
    return Arr.filter(function(item){
      return item!="X" && item!="O";
    });
  }
   function minimax(reboard,player){
     iter++;
     let array = availableSpots(reboard);
     if (winCondition(reboard, playerTurn))
     {
     return {score:-10};

    }
    else if (winCondition(reboard, computerTurn))
    {
    return 
    {score:10};

      }
  else if (array.length === 0)
  {
    return {score:0};

  }
     var moves = [];
     for(var i=0; i<array.length;i++){
       var move = {};
       move.index =  reboard[array[i]];
       reboard[array[i]] = player;
       if(player==computerTurn){
         var g = minimax(reboard, playerTurn);
       move.score = g.score;
       }
       else{
         var g = minimax(reboard, computerTurn);
        move.score = g.score;
       }
       reboard[array[i]] = move.index;
       moves.push(move); 
     }
    var bestMove;
     if(player === computerTurn){
       var bestScore = -10000;
       for(var i=0; i<moves.length;i++){
       if(moves[i].score > bestScore){
         bestScore = moves[i].score;
         bestMove = i;
       }
     }
     }
     else{
       var bestScore = 10000;
       for(var i=0; i<moves.length;i++){
         if(moves[i].score < bestScore){
           bestScore = moves[i].score;
           bestMove = i;
         }
       }
     }
     return moves[bestMove];
}

  function reset(){
    turns = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    count = 0;
    $(".box").text("");
  }
  function movement(turn,id){
    var spotTaken = $("#"+id).text();
    if(spotTaken!="X" ||spotTaken!="O" ){
      count++;
     $("#"+id).text(turn);
      turns[id]=turn;
      if(winCondition(turns,turn)){
        alert("you win!!");
        reset();
      }else if(count>8){
        alert("it was a draw");
        reset();
      }
      else{
        count++;
        var computerChoice = minimax(turns,computerTurn).index;
        console.log(computerChoice);
       $("#"+computerChoice).text(computerTurn);
        turns[computerChoice]=computerTurn;
        if(winCondition(turns,computerTurn)){
          alert("you lose!!");
          reset();
        }
        else if(count > 8){
          alert("it was a draw");
        }
      }

  }
  }
  $("#onePlayer").on("click",function(){
    $("#xOro").show();
    $("#chooseGame").hide();
  });
  $("#chooseX").on("click",function(){
    $("#xOro").hide();
    $("#gameBoard").show();
    computerTurn = "O";
    playerTurn = "X";
    $(".playerOneTurn").show();
    $(".playerOneTurn").html("<p>Computer's turn</p>");

  }); 
  $("#chooseO").on("click",function(){
    $("#xOro").hide();
    $("#gameBoard").show();
    computerTurn = "X";
    playerTurn = "O";
    $(".playerOneTurn").show();
    $(".playerOneTurn").html("<p>Computer's turn</p>");
  });
  $(".box").on("click",function(){
    var spot = $(this).attr("id");
    movement(playerTurn,spot);
  });
});
```

I created a pen for tic tac toe game in the pen above but when I try to play it gives me this message "can not read property score of undefined" I don't know why ? Can any one please help me?

Comment: Your pen throws a 404. Please update the url

Comment: Did you ever declare `reboard`? As in `var reboard = {}`? Is `let array` better than `var array`? Is it helpful that `array` scope is limited?

Comment: no i did not declare    reboard  it  is a function attribute that should be an Array ,    let array and var array both works the same for my code .@zer00ne

Answer (score 0):

Your minimax() returns {score} and then you are doing this:

```
 var g = minimax(reboard, computerTurn).score;
 move.score = g.score;
```

The 'g' has score value not the object, so below line will fail

```
move.score = g.score;
```

You should be doing:

```
var g = minimax(reboard, computerTurn).score;
 move.score = g;
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove (.score) the orginal code is var g = minimax(reboard, computerTurn);
 move.score = g.score;

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, `minmax()` tries to serve two masters ... and fails in the attempt.

- when called from `movement()`, `minmax()` is expected to return an object with an `.index` property.
- when called recursively, `minmax()` is expected to return an object with a `.score` property.

You could probably inform `minmax()` of the caller's needs and compose accordingly, however it's simpler for `minmax()` always to return an object with both properties, ie a `move` object. To do this, you can pass an index or even better an index encapsulated in an embryonic `move` object (to be returned with an added score).

With the required mods and a few simplifications, I ended up with this :

```
function minimax(reboard, player, move) {
    let array = availableSpots(reboard);
    if (winCondition(reboard, playerTurn)) {
        return $.extend(move, { score: -10 }); //  Yay!, returned object will be a `move` with an .index and a .score property.
    } else if (winCondition(reboard, computerTurn)) {
        return $.extend(move, { score: 10 }); // ... ditto ...
    } else if (array.length === 0) {
        return $.extend(move, { score: 0 }); // ... ditto ...
    }
    var moves = array.map(function(index) {
        var reboard_ = reboard.slice(0, index).concat(player).concat(reboard.slice(index + 1)); // to prevent mutation of reboard, work with a mutated clone.
        return minimax(reboard_, (player == computerTurn) ? playerTurn : computerTurn, { 'index': index }); // pass an embryonic `move` object.
    });
    if(player === computerTurn) {
        // Yay!, returned object will be a `move` with an .index and a .score property.
        return moves.reduce(function(best, move) {
            return (move.score > best.score) ? move : best;
        }, {'index': -1, 'score': -10000}); // starter object for the reduction
    } else {
        // ... ditto ...
        return moves.reduce(function(best, move) {
            return (move.score < best.score) ? move : best;
        }, {'index': -1, 'score': 10000}); // starter object for the reduction
    }
}
```

The only other change is in `movement()`, where the `minimax()` recursion is started :

```
var computerChoice = minimax(turns, computerTurn, { 'index': id }).index; // pass an embryonic `move` object
```

*untested*